# convert json before v.s. after rest api call

Tags: rest

This is a naïve question but I really wonder the difference.

If client side calls a rest API that gets a `JSON` response. Now, for some reason, I want to convert it into other files for example, `excel` or `csv`.

It's there any big differences I need to concern about:

let frontend convert the `JSON` into desired file **V.S.** let backend convert the result into desired file first then sends over the rest api.

In short, `backend -> JSON -> rest API -> frontend -> (target file)`  **V.S.** `backend -> JSON -> (target file) -> rest API -> frontend`

The only thing I know for sure is that if I decided to let `frontend` handle the work,
there is nothing backend to be changed and leave a lot of flexibility to API itself.

But I wonder the later case, does it have any benefits if backend processes and then sends the file directly?
Assume backend is `python` vs frontend `javascript`.
If the JSON data is relatively large (> 100000 rows), will it make any differences? Will the language itself made some performance boost (performance limitation in frontend) while process `JSON` to `target files`?

Comment: Is it equally simple to create such files? There might be more possibilities to create an Excel sheet using Python than using Javascript

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, equally simple, the JSON is well defined, the difference is to let backend convert vs frontend convert without talking about size

Comment: @NicoHaase but if I decided to let backend do the work, then API need to be config of course, to allow different types of target files.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question. First, you've asked for differences in relatively large JSON dumps, now the size is no longer relevant? It might take some time to properly convert a dump with more than 100.000 elements in the browser

Comment: @NicoHaase I just want to address your question "equally simple", i thought you mean in terms of implementation. Size matters, that why I mention `without talking about size`. we have some miscommunication

Comment: lots of REST APIs let you request the format of the response, e.g. /api/user/123?format=xml, /api/user/123?format=json etc. Implement as many formats as you need and let the backend do the work controlled by ?format=